# Django form doesn't runs form.is_valid

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-views

I'm working on a Django custom form:
I have debugged that form.is_valid function is not running even all the data comes in the view.

**models.py**

```
choices = (
   ('yes', 'Yes'),
   ('no', 'No'),
   ('not sure', 'Not Sure'),
)
class TaggedArticle(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tagging')
   category_fit = models.CharField(choices=choices, max_length=255)
   article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='articles')
   relevant_feedback = models.TextField(blank=True)
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
```

**forms.py**

```
class TagForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TaggedArticle
        fields = ('user', 'category_fit', 'article', 'relevant_feedback')
        widgets = {
            'category_fit': forms.RadioSelect()
        }
```

**views.py**

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_data = request.POST.copy()
        post_data.update({'user': request.user.pk})
        form = forms.TagForm(post_data)
        print('request recieved')
        if form.is_valid():
            tag = TaggedArticle()
            tag.user = request.user
            article = Article.objects.all().filter(id=form.cleaned_data['article'])
            tag.category_fit = form.cleaned_data['category_fit']
            tag.article = article
            tag.relevant_feedback = form.cleaned_data['relevant_feedback']
            tag.save()

        return HttpResponse('Tagged Successfully!', status=200)
```

**Update**
I think it's radio buttons error:
Here's how i'm getting this from my template:

```
<td><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="category_fit">Yes</label></td>
<td><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="category_fit">No</label></td>
<td><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="category_fit">Not Sure</label>
```

Help me, please!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
    if form.is_valid():
        tag = form.save(commit=False)
        tag.user = request.user
        tag.save()
   else:
        # Added else statment
        msg = 'Errors: %s' % form.errors.as_text()
        return HttpResponse(msg, status=400)
```

you need to add `value` attr to your `radio`:

```
<td><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="category_fit" value="yes">Yes</label></td>
<td><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="category_fit" value="no">No</label></td>
<td><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="category_fit" value="not sure">Not Sure</label>
                                                                     <!-- ^^^^^^^^^^  -->
```

Comment: your form has error, i updated the answer, you can try it

Comment: i think it's category_fit radio option's error, how I can use this radio buttons in my template? please!

Comment: do I have to add some attributes in `'category_fit': forms.RadioSelect()` inside my forms.py ?

Comment: now it return another error: `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Article'`

Comment: glad to help you! you should accept the answer for other people with the same troubles who will search the solution

Answer (score 0):

After Calling form.is_valid() , call form.errors and print that to know the expected input to the form.

```
form.is_valid()
print(form.errors)
```

**or**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

form.is_valid()
return HttpResponse(form.errors)
```

Comment: HttpResponse return category_fit!

Comment: it means there is some problem with the category_fit field while getting the form data

Comment: do I have to add some attributes in `'category_fit': forms.RadioSelect() inside my forms.py` ?

Comment: Yes, you need to add the value field as suggested by @bear brown